# Centering the div

Tags: html, css

Simple one that doesn't seem to want to work..

I want to centre a div inside a 100% wide div.

HTML.

```
<div id="body-outside">
    <div id="body-inside">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS.

```
#body-outside{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#F7B3DA;
}

#body-inside{
    width:1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#F7B3DA;
    float:left;
}
```

The content is staying on the left of the screen at the moment.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: don't float left

Comment: You're going to run into some problems with setting `#body-inside` so wide - mainly that smaller monitors won't be able to display the entire `<div>` without a horizontal scrollbar. Maybe consider using `max-width: 1280px` or something.

Comment: I looked into the stats and they seem to suggest that the vast majority of users are now using higher resolutions with a min of 1280 width. 95% upwards it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of `float:left;`. This pushes it to the left despite setting the margin to auto.

Comment: Perfect, I'll green tick this asap.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to think about using text-align: center in the body outside portion.

Comment: This will only center `#body-inside` if it is `inline-block`.